# Duda nombre ambiguo SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Hola buenas tardes como podria solucionar el error por el que me dice que el nombre es ambiguo, si quiero poder sacar la cantidad de votos de personas de género masculino del partido A**

```
    SELECT VOTOS 
      FROM ResultadoPorMesa 
INNER JOIN Mesas 
        ON ResultadoPorMesa.CodMesa = Mesas.CodMesa 
INNER JOIN PadronMasculino 
        ON Mesas.CodMesa = PadronMasculino.Mesa 
INNER JOIN Partidos 
        ON ResultadoPorMesa.CodPartido = partidos.CodPartido 
     WHERE CodPartido = '1'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cuando uses columnas en `SELECT` o `WHERE`, poné el alias de la tabla antes `alias.columna` para que sepa de que tabla sacarlo.

Comment: tienes que agregar el prefijo "Partidos" o "ResultadoPorMesa" en tu condición en el `WHERE`. Es lo mismo que hiciste en las condiciones de join

Comment: Y por cierto, poné el código _como texto, con formato_. El código en la imagen es prácticamente ilegible.

Comment: Lamak ahora me funciono con el WHERE , muchas gracias!